# Convert coordinate UTM to DMS

Tags: c#, arcgis, esri

I need to convert UTM to DMS. For example: x 6518585.31 y 13343143.32 -> degrees minutes seconds.

People refer to this library esri.arcgis.defensesolutions.dll, but I can't find where to download it.

Comment: All I had to do was to Google for "[esri.arcgis.defensesolutions.dll](https://www.google.com/search?q=esri.arcgis.defensesolutions.dll)".

Comment: It? 116 MB.   http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/index.cfm?fuseaction=download.main&downloadid=672

Comment: Yeah, pretty easy to find. Why didn't _you_ find it?

Comment: It's not something? http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/index.cfm?fuseaction=download.main&downloadid=671

Comment: I meant why didn't you find it before asking the question.

Comment: I was looking for. I was frightened by the size of the files.

Comment: Like I said, simple Google search found it on the first page.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/). You can download and use it at no cost for coordinate conversion. [Sample code](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/sample-code/ProjectCoordinate/) is available, but here's the relevant code for what you need to do. You can use http://spatialreference.org/ref/ to find the WKID for your UTM zone; I'm using `32642`, which is the WKID for UTM zone 42N based on WGS84.

```
var utmSpatialReferenceWkid = 32642;//UTM zone 42N based on WGS84
var pointUtm = new MapPoint(6518585.31, 13343143.32, utmSpatialReferenceWkid);
var pointLonLat = GeometryEngine.Project(pointUtm, SpatialReference.Wgs84);
var longitude = pointLonLat.X;
var latitude = pointLonLat.Y;
```

The defensesolutions DLL you mentioned is older technology, and you need an ArcGIS Desktop or Engine license to use it, which incurs a cost. Use ArcGIS Runtime instead.

Comment: I joined the project Esri.ArcGISRuntime.
Error: The type or namespace name 'Esri' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The project uses the library ESRI.ArcGis.*** version 10.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

coordinate system "Meters" to "Degrees Minutes Seconds"

```
            ISpatialReferenceFactory srEnv = new SpatialReferenceEnvironmentClass();
            var wgsIn = srEnv.CreateESRISpatialReferenceFromPRJFile(@"C:\111.prj");
            var wgsOut = srEnv.CreateESRISpatialReferenceFromPRJFile(@"C:\222.prj");

            var point = new PointClass();
            point.PutCoords(3304534.9530999996, 6859385.3066000007);
            point.Project(wgsIn);

            var dmsCoord = new DMSCoordinate
            {
                Precision = esriCoordinatePrecision.esriCPOneMeter,
                InputSpatialReference = wgsIn,
                OutputSpatialReference = wgsOut,
                Point = point
            };

            var dsd = dmsCoord.String;
```

dmsCoord.String Returns incorrect coordinates

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CoordinateSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoordinateSharp/) for exactly this.

Example

```
 UniversalTransverseMercator utm = new UniversalTransverseMercator("T", 32, 233434, 234234);
 Coordinate c = UniversalTransverseMercator.ConvertUTMtoLatLong(utm);
 Console.WriteLine(c); //Outputs DMS formatted coordinate by default.
```

You can also access individual lat/long properties within the `Coordinate` object.